# clustered MSMQ and WCF

Tags: wcf, msmq, cluster-computing

not sure which area this belongs in but think all 3 tags is appropriate.

Scenario:

Clustered environment (i.e 3 computers in 1 cluster)
using Transactional MSMQ
using WCF service to read messages from the queue.

in this instance, what happens when a messsage comes to the queue and passes it to WCF for processing? Will it process on all 3 computers at once for that 1 message? or will it be just 1 computer?

I want to make sure that if a node goes down, the other kicks in and continue but at the same time want to make sure that messages are not being processed multiple times (i.e 3 computers there and its been processed 3 times)

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a message arrives at a queue with three clients, only one client will consume the message.

In order to provide the kind of redundancy you want it is necessary to multicast your messages. This means each client has it's own input queue and you send the exact same message to all the queues.

Comment: thanks. how would i do the multicasting? would the msmq not be clustered, meaning incomng msgs will be placed there and the nodes would obtain it?

Comment: I am not sure how to cluster MSMQ. I have implemented multicasting by having the message sender just send to a list of queues one by one.

Comment: ah. unfortunately that maybe something i cannot do or have control of.

Comment: I am now almost done setting up the environment and leads me to further questions, or it could be my lack of sleep (extremely). I have 2 Nodes clustered. I have MSMQ clustered. When a messages comes in, it would be pointing to the MSMQ cluster. But for the WCF app which reads the queue (self hosted console app), where does this app sit? Both Nodes? Seperate computer in the domain? What if the computer which is running this WCF app fails? I want another computer to take over and continue processing, just like the clustered MSMQ. So I guess I need to cluster the WCF app? how?

Comment: Answered my own question there. install the WCF service app on the clustered nodes (Windows Service app for example) and create a clustered application or generic service for it. The problem I have now is that when it tries to check the queue to see if it exists using .\private$\queueName when it is running as a clustered service, it throws an error saying that the Message Queue service is not available, but it clearly is. Even tried it with <clusteredMSMQName\private$\<queueName>. no go.